# Angular JS ng-CSV

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, csv, download

We are using ng-csv to export as excel in our application. 
http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv

Issue: Unable to format cells like width ,background color etc . Hence the generated CSV/Excel file looks very clustered. The user need to manually expand columns if the header is big etc..

Anyone figured out how to format cells using ng-csv ? Or is there any other solution for exporting to excel other than ng-csv that works in all browsers ? (IE 10+). Stuck here. Kindly Help out.